# My for loop is not getting executed

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have a condition inside i have a loop when i run the code i am able to pass the condition, but inside my condition i have a loop which does not get executed.

this line above constructor

```
 currentDate = new Date();
```

this line inside the class

```
if (form.value.packType == "Per Week") {
            console.log("I could able to see this console");
            for (var a = this.currentDate.getDate(); a < 8; a++) {
                console.log("I could not see this console",a)
            }
    }
```

in my console i could able to see the "Per week" value but i an not able to see the console inside my log.

Could someone help me.

Comment: "Per week" or "per week" ?

Comment: i could able to pass the condition, only i could not able to see the value inside loop

Comment: Check if you have "Per week" by doing console.log(form.value.packType) before the if statment

Comment: what is the value of `this.currentDate.getDate()`, my guess is it is 28, so it won't loop through because you have a `a < 8` condition

Comment: I am confused: does console.log("Per Week"); execute or not ? Which one of console.log() doesn't log ?

Comment: what ever the current date might be but i should get 7 days from the current day so could you give me some sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, when you do this: `a = this.currentDate.getDate();` you'll get `28', which make the loop execution condition false and it doesn't run at all.

What you need is to get the current date day, and run a loop for 7 days, and use the `setDate()` method to get a date. This is how you should do that:

```
if (form.value.packType == "Per Week") {

    // get the current day 
    let currentDateDay = this.currentDate.getDate();

    // get the next 7 dates from currectDate
    for(var a=1;a<=7;a++){
        // Get the next date
        let nextDate = new Date();
        nextDate.setDate(currentDateDay+a);
        console.log(nextDate); 
    }
}
```

Link to [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/a21PhwI9EAMpAZ30ZTI3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Because todays date is 28(for example) so `a = 28` and you have condition like `a < 8` so condition gets false and it will out from loop without executing a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you log currentDate.getDate() in your console you will see that its value is 28. Since this is greater than 8 the loop is not executed.

```
console.log(currentDate.getDate())
```

Maybe you should clarify what the condition inside the loop is about to help you.